# test remote file if directory

Tags: unix

```
HOSTNAME=$1

#missing files will be created by chk_dir
for i in `cat filesordirectorieslist_of_remoteserver`
do

isdir=remsh $HOSTNAME "if [ -d $i ]; then echo dir; else echo file; fi"

if [ $isdir -eq "dir" ]
then

remsh $HOSTNAME "ls -d $i | cpio -o" | cpio -id
else

remsh $HOSTNAME "ls | cpio -o" | cpio -id
fi
done
```

i need simple solution for checking remote file is directory or file ?
thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "remote file"?

Comment: You know, it's safe to list a file with "ls -d".  So, assuming you didn't mean to leave the $i off of your second ls | cpio command, you don't need to bother testing for directories -- just ls -d $i each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add backticks around the first `remsh`:

```
isdir=`remsh $HOSTNAME "if [ -d $i ]; then echo dir; else echo file; fi"`
```

Answer (score 0):

This has worked for me on bash (Fedora):

```
ssh $REMOTEHOST [ -d /path/to/some/directory ]
```

or

```
ssh $REMOTEHOST [ -f /path/to/some/file ]
```

The exit status of 0 or 1 will reflect the existent/not-existent status of the directory/file on the remote host.

I use key exchange to avoid needing to provide credentials every time, so this can easily be scripted. I use this in a loop before doing a multiple subversion repository synchronization, to know if a new repository needs to be initialized.